# Replace value by variable, page load slowly jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, replace, load

I have a script which is perfectly working :

```
<script>
function aller(){
$('#container').animate({marginLeft : '0px'}, {duration:1});
retour();
}

function boucle(){
$('#container').animate({marginLeft : '0px'}, {duration:4000});
retour();
}

function retour(){
//Modify marginLeft value if needed
$('#container').animate({marginLeft : -400}, {duration:4000});
boucle();
}
</script>
```

But when I change the margin left "-400" by the variable I need :

```
$('#container').animate({marginLeft : $('.Image img:last').position().left}, {duration:4000});
```

The web page is very slow to load, I really don't understand because when I check if he find the value, it find it directly (by writing

> alert($('.Image img:last').position().left);

for exemple)

I don't know what it's loading because he knows the value !

The html part :

```
<body onLoad="aller();">
<div id="cont">
<div id="container">
    <div id="images" >
        <div class="Image"><img src="./Images/richard.jpg"/><div>
        <div class="Image"><img src="./Images/ivanovic.jpg"/><div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you !

Comment: Are you aware that calling those functions will force them to go back and forth over and over and over?

Comment: Yeah I know, this is not the problem here =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to call `retour()`, then have it call `boucle()` when its animation is done, and so on. But the call to `animate()` returns immediately, after just scheduling the animation. What you want to do is to register the other function as a callback on completion:

```
$('#container').animate({marginLeft : -400}, {duration:4000, complete:retour});
```

Comment: YES ! I think you get it. THIS is the problem, but now the animation is doing just one iteration and stop.. Edit: no it's good, just loading a little bit under each iteration =) Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here...you are calling the `retour()` function inside `boucle(),` which in turn calls `retour()` again, and so on ad infinitum....

```
function boucle(){
$('#container').animate({marginLeft : '0px'}, {duration:4000});
retour();
}

function retour(){
//Modify marginLeft value if needed
$('#container').animate({marginLeft : -400}, {duration:4000});
boucle();
}
```

This is causing an infinite loop.....thus slowing your page to a crawl

Not sure if thats the problem you're talking about, but it still is definitely a problem you need to address.. :)

Comment: Yeah I know and this in not the problem, because it is not laging at all when I don't put the variable in the loop !